# Still can't delete in SQL using JOIN

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sql-delete

I am using PostgreSQL. I saw other posts with people having trouble using join while deleting, which said to specify the table you are deleting from. I did that, and this is still not working. It says there is a "syntax error at or near 'Customers'. I am using the famous Northwind database.

```
DELETE Customers FROM Customers INNER JOIN Orders
ON Customers.CustomerID=Orders.CustomerID
WHERE Customers.CustomerID = 5;
```

The code doesn't really do anything useful, I just want to know why I can't delete using JOIN.

Answer (score 3):

As [documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-delete.html) you can't use `JOIN` like that in a DELETE statement. To join tables to the base table you need to use the `USING` clause:

```
DELETE FROM Customers 
using Orders
where Customers.CustomerID=Orders.CustomerID
  and Customers.CustomerID = 5;
```

This is equivalent to the SQL without a join:

```
delete from customers as c
where c.customerid = 5
and exists (select * 
            from orders o
            where o.customerid = c.customerid);
```

Comment: I see, looks like I didn't realize PostgreSQL was different on this. Thanks! Also, one thing, the last line, you meant o.customerid = c.customerid, right?

Answer (score 0):

A join in a delete will never work. If you want to ensure that the customer has an order, you could try something like this:

```
DELETE FROM Customers 
WHERE 
CustomerID = 5 AND
CustomerID IN (SELECT o.CustomerID FROM Orders o);
```

Comment: I see, looks like I didn't realize PostgreSQL was different on this. Thanks!